# Is it possible to reuse selenium session in chrome headless?

Tags: java, selenium

I have an upload sequence code that I am running using remote debugging to save me verification each time. I was wondering if it was possible for a session to be both headless and in remote debugging seeing as I cant use computer while it runs for some reason. if chrome is minimized it fails to find certain elements.

I have

```
     // connect to remote debugging
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222");
```

also the piece of code that fails when chrome is minimized  is:

```
     // click on zip
     try {
         WebElement element_1=driver_2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'zip.zip']"));
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver_2, 120);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element_1));
         element_1.click();
     }catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {System.out.println("no such element");}
```

Comment: do you want to run your above code in headless mode?

Comment: if you want to run your code in headless mode, you can do it by adding chrome option headless. ```options.setHeadless(true);```